# Greatest $n$ is possible? in $10^n$ as a divisor of $1995!$

Tags: divisibility, factorial, integers

**Problem**: $1995!$ has a number of divisors that are powers of $10$, i.e. $10^n$. Find the greatest possible $n$, $n\in Z$

**My solution**: I reckon that the maximum $n$ equals to the number of trailing zeroes of $1995!$ I think there are two sources of zeroes: numbers from $1$ to $1995$ that are divisible by $10$ and numbers that are divisible by $5$ but not by $10$.

1) The number of numbers that are divisible by $5$ but not divisible by $10$ is $200$. Thus, they give at least $200$ zeros. However, some numbers are divisible by $25$, which means they contain two $5$'s in their prime factorization, which means that they give one more zero each. There are $40$ such numbers. Similarly, there are numbers that are divisible by $125$, they give one more zero each, there are $8$ such numbers. Finally, there are $2$ numbers that are divisible by $625$, they give one more zero each. In total, all these numbers give $250$ zeros.

2) There are $199$ numbers that are  divisible by $10$. Among these numbers there are 19 numbers that are also divisible by $100$ and $1$ number that is divisible by $1000$. Thus, all these numbers give $219$.

Totally, we have $250+219 = 469$ trailing zeros, which gives the answer.

However, the answer key says I'm wrong and the answer is $496$.

I'd like to know where my reasoning is wrong and how I can reach the correct answer.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I'd just focus on multiples of $5$, $25$, $125$, etc.

Comment: You seem to be miscounting the contribution of numbers like $50$, $150$, $250$, etc.

Comment: @AnginaSeng could you please sketch how you would do that?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Hm... I thought I mentioned them in the second part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given is correct. To find the number of zeros, we have to coubt the number of $5$ that are contanied in $1995!$. This is given by:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{4}\left\lfloor \frac{1995}{5^i}\right\rfloor$$ 
Note that $4$ is the integer part of $\log_5(1995)$. This sum gives as result $399+79+15+3=496$, so there are $496$ trailing zeros in $1995!$.
You can find some references here: https://www.purplemath.com/modules/factzero.htm and https://www.handakafunda.com/number-of-trailing-zeros/.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $$\sum_{i=1}^4\left\lfloor \frac{1995}{5^i}\right\rfloor?$$

Comment: @Angina Seng: yes it is. Sorry, corrected. The result doesn't change.

Comment: But there are $496$ zeros at the end of $1995!$, just as the OP's textbook says.

Comment: @Angina Seng: my answer is correct, so the answer given must be wrong.

Comment: No, your answer is false. Your formula is incorrect.

Comment: Why is it incorrect?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula for the correct formula.

Comment: The sum is $399+79+15+3 = 496$.

Comment: No, because when $i>\lfloor\log_5(1995)\rfloor$, then: $$\left \lfloor \frac{1995}{5^i}\right \rfloor = 0$$

Comment: The three values in my sum are for i=1, 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: @Peter Phipps: yes, I have edied. The tool I have used gave an incorrect answer. However, is my approach correct?

Comment: Yes it is but your answer still contains the wrong formula and still says there are 614 trailing zeros.

Comment: @Matteo get rid of the multiplication by $i$.

Comment: I think now it's all correct; can you confirm?